Why stereo headphones have resistance/impedance between left and right (tip and ring of TRS) twice that of nominal?
I've found out measuring resistance for two headphones (~32 and ~50 ohms nominal) that resistance/impedance between left and right (tip and ring of TRS connector) is about twice that of nominal (sleeve to tip/ring). How is it made so, and what for? I was not able to find that out neither via web search, nor reading Wikipedia.
I have one TRS plug disconnected from speakers and impedance is infinite for each T/R/S combination, so it does not seem to be how TRS plugs are made (my initial hypothesis).
Maybe related: Mono headphones to stereo jack



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I know you've figured it out by now, but a schematic makes it very clear.

Measuring resistance between the sleeve and either tip or ring will have one speaker in circuit.
Measuring resistance between the tip and ring will have both in series so the resistance should be double.


If the common ground wire (SLEEVE) is disconnected the pair of speakers will be connected in series but in anti-phase. (Note the polarity indicators I've added.) This affects the sound dramatically:

The speakers can only respond to the difference between the two channels. Imagine a bass guitar or drum signal (usually in the centre of the stereo panorama) peaking on both L and R at the same time; there will be no difference in voltage between the L and R so that component of the audio will not excite the speakers.
Any instruments or voices that are off-centre in the stereo panorama will sound.
The overall result is a "hole-in-the-head" effect on headphones and a weird "hole-in-the-middle" effect on loudspeakers. You can demonstrate the loudspeaker effect quite easily by reversing the polarity of one speaker and sitting in the middle of the stereo field. For headphones you could load a stereo MP3 into something like Audacity and (I assume it's possible) invert one of the channels to make it out of phase.


Thanks. What I have not figured out (I understand that is another question but it might be off-limits here) that another speakers which I just made work again started to output mono sound. In the process of making them work as stereo again I discovered wire (one or both not sure now that plug was cut) from sleeve was damaged, but tip and ring seemed to be intact (I did nothing to them and speakers work as stereo again). How could speakers become mono in such case?

@Martian2020 If the Sleeve wire is broken, then all current will flow through tip-L-R-ring terminals, i.e. the same current will flow though both speakers, making them produce the same sound.

@tobalt, is it for "virtually" all amplifiers? Is it damaging to the amplifier to use such speakers (like claimed in link for another QA in my question about mono-2-stereo)?

See the update.

I wouldn't call it "hole in the head/middle". Usually, the antiphase effect just leads to a strong attenuation of low frequencies as these are most often in phase. Note that the sound will be usual mono sound, so there is no "middle".

That is because both left and right speakers are connected to same ground terminal, so if you have 32 ohms between left and ground, and 32 ohms between right and ground, you will have 64 ohms between left and right as they will be in series.

thanks, just got it figured out myself, but your answer was before I did that and realized it is so easy question - wanted to delete. It is interesting how writing and posting helps thinking :-)

@Martian2020 - Speaking does it as well. It sounds like you might like to have a rubber duck around. Believe me, he helps me with more than just coding. He found some lost keys the other day. Maybe if you don't want people to know you are using him, you could send him emails, or at least draft them, although he might take a while to reply.

@MichaelHarvey, your name is familiar: I used to work with Michael Harvey (not sure of exact spelling though) at the end of 20x century. He was a manager at the time.

@Martian2020 From 1997 to 2006 I worked in Bristol, UK,  for Capita PLC, a business services provider, but I was never a manager.
